# Attachments missing in Evolution since 12.10 upgrade

Tags: 12.10, evolution

So I upgraded to 12.10 few days ago and now I cannot access attachments in my e-mails any more (on top of the bug that stops me from sending attachments larger than a certain size). Any idea how I can fix the problem?

The attachments used to be under the expandable from -field in the middle of the screen.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/05QG1.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

If you get:

```
WriteStream: MAPI error MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED (0×80004005)
```

Then the solution can be found here:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openchange/+bug/1073991

Shortcut: (which you will find somewhere on the above link) : install this package"

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openchange/+bug/1073991/+attachment/3428716/+files/openchange.tar.gz